GLMs where response variable is calculated from multiple data points in a time series?
Hopefully this isn't too broad of a topic: I'm a student research assistant working with matched gene expression counts data in a time series. As a simplified example, say I have two sets of time series data A and B gathered from count data for each timepoint in T (here from NB sampling):
> A
[1] 1114 1062  679  666  359  620  753
> B
[1] 2385 2125 2097 2213 1117 1022 3116
> T
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

I am interested in computing a third set which involves a set of operations both from neighboring time points and across the two matched series:
> C <- c()
> T_avg <- c()

# Not the real computation, but I want to understand this simple case first
> for (i in 1:length(T)-1){
+   C_val <- (A[i] - A[i+1])/(B[i] + B[i+1]) 
+   C <- append(C,C_val)
+   
+   T_val <- (T[i] + T[i+1])/2
+   T_avg <- append(T_avg,T_val)
+ }
> 

From here I set up a model and identify the trend across time:
> data <- data.frame(C=C,time=T_avg)
> data
             C time
1  0.011529933  0.5
2  0.090715301  1.5
3  0.003016241  2.5
4  0.092192192  3.5
5 -0.122019635  4.5
6 -0.032141131  5.5
> model <- lm(C~time, data=data)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = C ~ time, data = data)

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
-0.05050  0.05061 -0.01516  0.09594 -0.09635  0.01546 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.07299    0.06401   1.140    0.318
time        -0.02193    0.01854  -1.182    0.303

Residual standard error: 0.07757 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.259, Adjusted R-squared:  0.07376 
F-statistic: 1.398 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.3025

However, this approach seems extremely rudimentary to me. In particular I'm running into these problems:

Handling replicates: if A[x] and A[x+1] have differing numbers of replicates (or A[x] and B[x]), C[x] can't be computed easily without throwing away batch information by just averaging values
Leveraging knowledge of the distribution of A and B: We know each A[x] and B[x] is drawn from a negative binomial, so it feels like a GLM could utilize this info somehow?
Expanding to multiple linear regression for different groups e.g. C_1 vs C_2 is under-powered in a linear model, so a GLM + LRT seems like it would be beneficial, but then what link function would I use for C when it's derived from multiple NBs?
Independence: Since A[x], A[x+1], B[x], and B[x+1] are all interdependent, I'm thinking this needs to be accounted for somehow.

I'm wondering if there is a way to utilize the original data A and B in the regression instead? Or if there's another approach I should be thinking of? I'm having trouble finding related topics online anywhere.
Apologies in advance if I've gotten any terminology/formatting wrong; I'm still getting my feet wet in this field. Thanks!
